# Set an existing branch to detached HEAD (after `git rebase --onto`)

Tags: git, git-branch, git-rebase, git-detached-head

When I have a detached HEAD that's several commits ahead of an existing branch, what's the right command(s) to advance that branch to the detached HEAD without changing anything in my working directory?

Context: I just ran `git rebase --onto mybranch SHA1 SHA2`, and now I've got a detached HEAD at `REBASED-SHA2`.  Now I want to advance `mybranch` to REBASED-SHA2. I could create a new branch at REBASED-SHA2 (`git checkout -b temp`), delete the old branch (`git branch -d mybranch`), and rename the new branch (`git branch -m temp mybranch`). But that's a lot of typing, and might require even more typing if I had to set up tracking to the remote `mybranch`.

Is there a shorter way to do what I want, which is just to "advance" mybranch to a later commit?

Comment: `git checkout mybranch && git merge --ff-only SHA2`

Comment: @Guildenstern - Ahh, yeah. I should have thought of `merge` for this case. For some reason I was thinking that merge only works for branches, but of course it works for SHAs too. Thanks!  BTW, I had a mistake in my question (that I just edited to fix) because the detached head won't be at SHA2, it'll be at a new commit that resulted from rebasing SHA2 on top of `mybranch`.  If you want to turn your comment into an answer (with the correct target of REBASED-SHA2) then I'll happily accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`git checkout -B mybranch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout#Documentation/git-checkout.txt--Bltnew-branchgt) moves the `mybranch` tip label to (or creates it at) your current checkout, because since no specific target commit was given  `@` aka `HEAD` is the default.